# Generate random numbers which have a specific average in c

Tags: c, random

I want to generate random numbers in the range 3000 to 6000 in c.
I am using `6000-rand()%3000;` But a lot of results I get are close to 5000 and I want them to be diverse with average around 4500, so they are kind of equally distributed. I could get to a function `randi()` in matlab but I need to do it in C. Any suggestions how to get this done in c?

Comment: If you can use C++: Don´t use rand, but good methods like MT from `<random>` together with the uniform distribution. If you´re limited to C ... maybe search a lib for the same thing.

Comment: What compiler and standard library are you using? Your formulation (`6000-rand()%3000`) should average to 4500.5 over a large sample. How large a sample did you use to verify its behavior?

Comment: I need to get 96 random numbers and most of the generated results are above 5000.

Comment: You didn't post a complete or even a partial code sample. Did you seed the `rand()` function, for example with `srand(timer(NULL))`? And please note: "random" does not mean "equally distributed".

Comment: Actually I am working on my university server through ssh and they do not have    ctime.h    library loaded and I cannot ask them to add it, and I am not using any seed.

Comment: In C `rand()` will generate the same sequence every time unless it is seeded. It's hard to believe that a uni server has no time related functions available.

Comment: @shreyaskodupuganti, I believe you mean `time.h` not `ctime.h`. `#include <ctime>` is valid in C++, but the library is `#include <time.h>` in C. If you did not know this and you were trying to include ctime.h, then try Weather Vane's comment (`srand(time(NULL));`) with `#include <time.h>`.

Comment: Note: if you want "numbers in the range 3000 to 6000", use `6000-rand()%3001` or `3000 + rand()%3001`.